# Is there any way to open a node (or babel node) command line interface within a mocha test context?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mocha.js

I'm developing using node/webpack/reactjs with testing leveraged by mocha.

My productivity is vastly better than it was when using other javascript ecosystems but is still well below that which I achieve in Python when working on the service side.

In Python, I can develop using `ipdb.set_trace()` or `ipython.embed()` to open a command line in the context of a test. This is an excellent way to accelerate development because I can inspect and interactively tinker with all aspects of the data and code at the line where I am investigating or changing stuff.

Is there any way to do this using mocha tests? It would mean I could use javascript at the command line to inspect the current variable context interactively.  I can painstakingly emulate it by requiring bits and pieces in babel-node and then copy pasting lines of code.

In short, I'd like to be able to do something like this inside a test file:

```
  it('thingy meets expectations', () => {
    let thingy = {name: 'thingy'};
    node-babel.embed();
  });
```

so that when I run the test at the command line, something like this happens (where I type `thingy` at the command line which appears during the test):

```
$ npm run test -- --grep='thingy meets expectations'

> sosadmin_front_end@1.0.0 test ...front_end
> mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive "--grep=object: Form"



  object: Form
    // babel-node version=6.11.4 embeded at L223 ...front_end/tests/foo.js
    > thingy
    { name: 'thingy' }
```

Comment: WebStorm is an excellent IDE that allows [debugging during testing](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/debugging-javascript-unit-tests.html). I haven't used that feature myself, but might be something to look at. You can add a breakpoint or use `debugger;` which will stop execution of the test and let you inspect in-scope variables.

Comment: Have you tried to use [`node --inspect`](http://www.mattzeunert.com/2016/06/01/node-v8-inspector-inspect.html) to execute the tests? You can then add breakpoints and have the DevTools console available.